# Adding An ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently attempting to save an ArrayList of Strings to an ArrayList of Arrays of Strings. Below code shows the basics of what I'm attempting.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groupCollection= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
groupCollection.add(m_listItems);
```

I add Strings to `m_listItems` using the same `.add()` functionality and it adds string correctly.

But in the debugger, when I attempt to add `m_listItems` (that does infact have an array of values in it) into the first index of `groupCollection`, it adds a null array into the first index.

[image]

Comment: From the example you provided, the m_listItems contains no items (size = 0).

Comment: Oops, did you really mean null array? If so, undo my edit :)

Comment: Your snippet creates an empty list, then puts nothing in it. You shouldn't be surprised to find it remains empty!

Comment: The code you posted is useless, since it doesn't demonstrate any problem. If you're expecting different results, include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you're expecting and why.

Comment: @zapl I undid that part of the edit, since there is already an answer which replies to "null array". That edit invalidated this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, that's not a null, just an empty array list!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add objects to your m_listitems list, m_listitems.add("foo"); execute you groupCollection.add(m_listItems); method and you should see a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Answers above are certainly correct.
Just to add few details.
We created a ArrayList of ArrayList of String named *groupCollection*. And ArrayList named *m_listItems*.
Create another ArrayList for example *n_ListItems*. And add strings to both ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        m_listItems.add("Hello");
        m_listItems.add("Welcome");
ArrayList<String> n_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        n_listItems.add("Hi!");
        n_listItems.add("Wel..");
        n_listItems.add("Come..");
```

Add both lists to *groupCollection*.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groupCollection= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        groupCollection.add(m_listItems);
        groupCollection.add(n_listItems);
```

We have added 2 arraylists to our ArrayList of ArrayList of String. To see the working of this program, I am displaying list using *Iterator*.

```
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> iterator = groupCollection.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

This will give output as follows.

```
[Hello, Welcome]
[Hi!, Wel.., Come..]
```

Now we can clearly see the way this program is working.